# In C# or Java, is it possible to generate a PDF without reading the font?

Tags: java, c#, pdf

In C# or Java, is it possible to generate a PDF file using a specific font, but without reading the data of this font? It is okay if the font is not embedded in this file, so that the user who opens this file will need to have the font in his or her computer.

I have looked at PdfSharp and PDF Clown. Both of the two libaries seem to need to read the data of the font before generating the PDF file. This is problematic. PdfSharp throws an exception for the font I specify, because it does not support the data format of this font. For PDF Clown, it seems that I need to specify the font file path, but it is not easy to find the file path.

Is it possible to simply specify a font name and a font size, and then use this font in a PDF file, just like what people do in HTML CSS?

Comment: In contrast to HTML files (for which the layout generation only happens in the browser of the viewing user) PDF files already come with a fixed, pre-computed layout. And to be able to pre-compute the layout, a PDF generator needs to know at least the metrics of a font it uses, e.g. the widths of each glyph therein.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to write a PDF without a font, and it be perfectly readable in any reader as long as it's not recent Acrobat DC! However there is no guarantee what may be displayed, often characters are simply shown as boxes.

[image]

```
%PDF-1.7
%‰«Íï
1 0 obj <</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R>> endobj
2 0 obj <</Type/Pages/Count 1/Kids[14 0 R]>> endobj
3 0 obj <</Type/Font/Subtype/Type1/BaseFont/Times-Roman/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding>> endobj
4 0 obj <</Type/Font/Subtype/Type0/BaseFont/Ming/Encoding/UniCNS-UTF16-H/DescendantFonts[5 0 R]>> endobj
5 0 obj <</Type/Font/Subtype/CIDFontType0/BaseFont/Ming/CIDSystemInfo<</Registry(Adobe)/Ordering(CNS1)/Supplement 7>>/FontDescriptor 6 0 R>> endobj
6 0 obj <</Type/FontDescriptor/FontName(Ming)/FontBBox[-200 -200 1200 1200]/Flags 6/ItalicAngle 0/Ascent 1000/Descent -200/StemV 80>> endobj
7 0 obj <</Type/Font/Subtype/Type0/BaseFont/Mincho/Encoding/UniJIS-UTF16-H/DescendantFonts[8 0 R]>> endobj
8 0 obj <</Type/Font/Subtype/CIDFontType0/BaseFont/Mincho/CIDSystemInfo<</Registry(Adobe)/Ordering(Japan1)/Supplement 6>>/FontDescriptor 9 0 R>> endobj
9 0 obj <</Type/FontDescriptor/FontName(Mincho)/FontBBox[-200 -200 1200 1200]/Flags 6/ItalicAngle 0/Ascent 1000/Descent -200/StemV 80>> endobj
10 0 obj <</Type/Font/Subtype/Type0/BaseFont/Batang/Encoding/UniKS-UTF16-H/DescendantFonts[11 0 R]>> endobj
11 0 obj <</Type/Font/Subtype/CIDFontType0/BaseFont/Batang/CIDSystemInfo<</Registry(Adobe)/Ordering(Korea1)/Supplement 2>>/FontDescriptor 12 0 R>> endobj
12 0 obj <</Type/FontDescriptor/FontName(Batang)/FontBBox[-200 -200 1200 1200]/Flags 6/ItalicAngle 0/Ascent 1000/Descent -200/StemV 80>> endobj
13 0 obj <</Length 292>>
stream
q
50 50 m
100 200 l
200 50 l
1 0 0 rg
f
Q
q
0 0 1 rg
BT
/TmRm 24 Tf
1 0 0 1 50 760 Tm
(Hello, world!) Tj
ET
BT
/Song 24 Tf
1 0 0 1 50 670 Tm
(O`Y}) Tj
ET
BT
/Mincho 24 Tf
1 0 0 1 50 640 Tm
<30533093306b3061306f> Tj
ET
BT
/Batang 24 Tf
1 0 0 1 50 610 Tm
<c548b155d558c138c694> Tj
ET
Q
q
Q
q
Q

endstream
endobj

14 0 obj
<</Type/Page/MediaBox[0 0 595 842]/Rotate 0/Resources<</Font<</TmRm 3 0 R/Song 4 0 R/Mincho 7 0 R/Batang 10 0 R>>>>/Contents 13 0 R/Parent 2 0 R>>
endobj

xref
0 15
0000000000 65536 f 
0000000015 00000 n 
0000000060 00000 n 
0000000112 00000 n 
0000000202 00000 n 
0000000307 00000 n 
0000000455 00000 n 
0000000596 00000 n 
0000000703 00000 n 
0000000855 00000 n 
0000000998 00000 n 
0000001106 00000 n 
0000001260 00000 n 
0000001404 00000 n 
0000001747 00000 n 

trailer
<</Size 15/Root 1 0 R>>
startxref
1911
%%EOF
```

Here is that PDF as written in MS NotePad (with a little help beforehand from a few  .exe's). So we can simply write that text as characters but not know if a viewer may be able to use them. Hence the mandatory PDF/A requirement that fonts must be embeded to be a "Port"able.Document.